# Search query from Edittext to Listview row animation

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-listview

I have a Listview and a Edittext is below the Listview. When user enters something in Edittext and press Send, it is appended as listview row.

When user press Send button, I want the that text should comes from bottom in a animation.

I have no idea where to start. Please help me as I am very new to android animations

Comment: Please identify the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Answer (score 1):

To start, use Listview with `android:stackFromBottom="true"` attribute to stack items from bottom.
And when you click send button, add the edittext data to the arraylist you use for the adapter and then call notifydatasetchanged.

Example:

`myarraylist.add("New Item");adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

For listview item animation refer this: [Implementing-Google-Plus-Style-ListView-Animations-on-Android](http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Implementing-Google-Plus-Style-ListView-Animations-on-Android)

Comment: The link was helpful.... but now the animation is also called when keyboard show and keyboard hide events are fired, when I am scrolling or every time when getView() is called. How do I make sure that animations on view are only called when getView() is called through adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Thanks